# Error con Multer - single(' ')

Tags: nodejs, express, multer

Intento cargar una imagen en la api para visualizar el dato con insomnia pero al momento de aplicar el código multer a mi ruta, me da error. Esto es lo que intento:

Carpeta librerías: **Multer.js**
No uso ES6 como ven, con los modulos

```
const multer = require('multer')
const uuid =  require('uuid')
const path = require('path')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:'uploads', //Carpeta para cargar las imágenes en svr
    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
module.exports = storage
```

En carpeta rutas: **photo.js**

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const photo = require('../controllers/photo-controller');
    const storage = require('../libs/multer');
    
//Intento usar single para subir una única imagen
    router.post('/home',storage.single('image'),photo.createPhoto)
    
    module.exports = router;
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\proyecto\src\routes\photo.js:14
router.post('/home',storage.single('image'))                            
                           ^
TypeError: storage.single is not a function...
```

Por qué no puedo ingresar al metodo single de multer?
Agradezco la ayuda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como pone en la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage) luego de crear el motor para guardar las fotos en el disco, tienes que pasar dicho motor a la función `multer` que es el que te devolverá los diferentes métodos para la subida de las imágenes.

```javascript
const multer = require('multer')
const uuid =  require('uuid')
const path = require('path')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:'uploads', //Carpeta para cargar las imágenes en svr
    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
// Te falta esto
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
module.exports = upload
```

Comment: Así es, me falto documentarme mejor antes de preguntar. Lo solucione con el mismo export :  ` module.exports = multer({storage})` que viene siendo su explicación. Muchas gracias por su tiempo